# Outliers and influential observations in elastic net logistic regression

Tags: logistic, outliers, elastic-net, leverage

My dataset has many biomarkers and the boxplots of these variables show the presence of many outliers. However, these 'outliers' are real data and not misread observations. I want to use elastic net logistic regression to see the association of these biomarkers with a binary outcome. Because my sample size is small and some biomarkers are correlated, I need some regularization. However, I'm not sure if the presence of outliers is a problem for elastic net logistic regressions (I assume it's going to affect the fit adversely because the estimation is still likelihood based). I could only find an R package called [enetLTS](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/enetLTS/enetLTS.pdf) that does a robust version of the elastic net regression.

I'd like to know if it's better to use this technique or there are other methods that I didn't find. Is there a package that can help identify the outliers and influential observations appropriately so that I can remove those and rerun the regression (if that is suggested at all)? I have found a [link](http://web.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/~susanavinga/SOUND/Deliverable_4.2/Dataset3-BRCA/BRCA_OutlierDetection.html) that shows sometimes fitting a GLM with the selected variables fails to identify the outliers.

Comment: See [leverage-values-for-ridge-regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315780/what-are-the-leverage-values-for-ridge-regression/316306#316306) and https://www.osti.gov/pages/servlets/purl/1337112,    https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1226319214000751

Comment: Thanks for the links. Do you know about any software implementation (e.g. available R packages)?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know about implemantations